# Procesado de imágenes en python

Tags: python

estoy realizando un estudio procesando imágenes obtenidas de satélites. El problema que tengo es que al procesar una imagen para corregirla, en vez de obtener una variedad de valores en la imagen resultante, solo me aparece el perfil de la misma. Alguien sabe a qué se puede deber?

```
 -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import cv2

Parámetros banda TIRS
Ml=0.00033420
Al=0.10000
K1=774.8853
K2=1321.0789

bandaTIRSparque2=cv2.imread('bandaTIRS2.tif',-1)
BandaTIRSmodificada=np.array(bandaTIRSparque2[:],np.float)

for f in range(len(bandaTIRSparque2)):
      for c in range(len(bandaTIRSparque2[f])):
          if bandaTIRSparque2[f][c]!=0: 
                 BandaTIRSmodificada[f][c]=float((K2/np.log((K1/(Ml*bandaTIRSparque2[f][c]+Al))+1))*255)

cv2.imwrite('bandaTIRSmodificada.tif',BandaTIRSmodificada)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un link a la imagen original para que podamos reproducir el ejemplo? Normalmente, las imágenes tienen varios canales. Tal como estás leyendo la imagen deberías tener 4 canales (R; G; B; alpha). En tu ejemplo parece que no lo estás teniendo en cuenta.

Comment: Tal como yo las descargué, son una imagen individual por cada canal. De esta forma el procesado debería ser más sencillo que si en una sola imagen se almacenaran todos los canales,no? En cuanto al enlace, la imagen es de el 12 de julio de 2015. La imagen una vez recortada con qgis delimita solo la zona del Parque Natural do Xurés, en la frontera entre España y Portugal.  http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/

Comment: http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/ltaauth//sno18/ops/l1/2015/204/031/LC82040312015193LGN00.tar.gz?id=rllctcnalmltd7krvemcc79gi1&iid=LC82040312015193LGN00&did=262274688&ver=production

Comment: El enlace que adjuntas es 1Gb. ¿estás seguro que eso es la imagen?

Comment: En los siguientes enlaces se pueden descargar la imagen original así como la que me devuelve el script.

https://db.tt/nlvoBOsS   --> imagen original
https://db.tt/X1j5SUoy   --> imagen modificada

Answer (score 2):

Después de mirar la imagen, es una imagen en BN por lo que no tiene más canales.

Prueba lo siguiente y dime si te resuelve el problema:

```
 -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

# Parámetros banda TIRS
Ml = 0.00033420
Al = 0.10000
K1 = 774.8853
K2 = 1321.0789

# Uso el nombre de la imagen enlazada en los comentarios
orig = cv2.imread('bandaTIRparque1.tif',-1) 

# Creo una copia a la que le voy a modificar los datos diferentes a cero
nueva = orig.copy()

# Con numpy puedo hacer operaciones vectorizadas por lo que
# voy a modificar solo los píxeles que cumplan la condición valor != 0
indexes = orig != 0
nueva[indexes] = (K2 / np.log((K1 / (Ml * orig[indexes] + Al)) + 1)) * 255

cv2.imwrite('bandaTIRSmodificada.tif', nueva)
```

Varias preguntas/observaciones.

- Si usas [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) no es necesario que uses `math`.
- Importas `matplotlib.image` pero no lo usas, al menos en la porción de código que has pegado.
- [opencv](/questions/tagged/opencv) no sería necesario para lo que haces ya que puedes usar [matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib) (`plt.imread`, `plt.imsave`).

La imagen final que me está quedando es similar a la primera pero *escalada*:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, la verdad es que funcionó perfectamente para calibrar las imágenes. Sin embargo, intenté utilizar el mismo método para calcular uno de los índices que me da problemas y no me funciona dando el siguiente error: TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

El código sería:

    BandaBAI1=bandaRparque1.copy()
    EXCLUIDOS = bandaRparque1!=0
    BandaBAI1[EXCLUIDOS]=float((1.0/((0.1-       BandaRmodificada[EXCLUIDOS])**2+(0.06-  BandaNIRmodificada[EXCLUIDOS])**2))*255)

    cv2.imwrite('indiceBAI1.tif',BandaBAI1)